# Change json object response

Tags: jquery, json

I have following response in my console .

```
 [Object { entity_id=5862, parent_id=5740, label="Cycling", more...}]
```

I want this to be shown as .

```
[{ entity_id:5862,parent_id:5740,label: "cycling",....}]
```

I want the Object to be removed from this . Basically want a json string .Please help me how can I get response like this . Thanks.

Comment: you have to push in []

Answer (score 0):

Try with [**serializeArray**](http://api.jquery.com/serializearray/) function like

```
input.serializeArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a json object you can acces to the data with [ ] and the position integer

Answer (score 0):

When your object is `var data`, and for whatever reason you need it to be an element of an array, simply wrap it in brackets:

```
var data = { }; // your object

data = [ data ];

console.debug( data );
```